# Ошибка компиляции. Как исправить?

Tags: android-studio, firebase, gradle, flutter

пытаюсь создать мобильное приложение с использованием firebase. делаю по уроку с ютуба

но при компиляции выдает ошибку:

```
* Error running Gradle:
ProcessException: Process "C:\Users\Fuck\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_app\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\Fuck\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_app\android\app\build.gradle' line: 24

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> ASCII

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 25s
  Command: C:\Users\Fuck\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_app\android\gradlew.bat app:properties

Finished with error: Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.
```

Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Ругается на файл `Gradle`.
1) Во многих случаях `Firebase` требует миграции на `AndroidX`, вы это сделали? 
2) При подключение `Firebase` необходима отредактировать файл `Gradle`, вы это сделали? 
[Документация как подключать Firebase](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/firebase)

Comment: Если хотите чтобы вам помогли предоставите следующие файлы: `C:\Users\Fuck\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_app\android\app\build.gradle` и `C:\Users\Fuck\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_app\android\build.gradle`

Comment: Первый пункт не сделал ибо не понимаю что это и как, второ пункт сделал

Comment: https://toster.ru/q/681423 это ссылка на этот же вопрос в тостере и там я привел содержимое файла /android/app/build.gradle

Comment: Ответил на ваш вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исправите ваши файлы на те которые я предоставил ниже, и попробуйте собрать проект заново. Перед тем как начать сборку необходимо выполнить следующую команду внутри вашего проекта (CMD): `flutter clean`

### [Что такое AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx)

**...\pubspec.yaml**

```
...
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.2.2 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # Icons
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  # Firebase
  firebase_core: ^0.4.0+9
  firebase_analytics: ^5.0.2
...
```

---

**...\android\gradle.properties:**

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
```

---

**...\android\app\build.gradle:**

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.flutter_app"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

---

**...\android\build.gradle:**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.71'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, Вы помогли!